# Why am I getting this error while using Python dict.setdefault?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, setdefault

```
dict.setdefault('Name','').str('Name 1')
```

I want to append 'Name' to the dictionary directly in a for loop and if the name is not available, I want it to be an empty string. Can we get this using setdefault?

When I use the above code, I get error as -

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. `setdefault` will return a string, as the error message suggests; the string is the new value in the dictionary. What are you trying to do with the string?

Comment: Given that `.setdefault` either returns the existing value or the default `''`, what did you expect from `.str`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe @APerson  This is the default method `setdefault(key,[ ]).append(value)` But instead of list, I want a string.

Comment: Sure, but that example isn't calling `.list`. It's calling `.append` **on** a list. So why access `.str`, an attribute strings definitely don't have?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, I was hoping for default to be an empty string instead of a list. That's why.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but **the default is the second argument to `setdefault`**, per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault). Exactly like the example you have, where the default is an empty list *passed as the second argument*. So `.setdefault('Name', '')` achieves what you say what you want, and it's not clear to me at all why you've tacked `.str('Name 1')` on to that. The error message is pretty clear: strings don't have a `str` method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you are looking to do because `str` is immutable, you will always need to construct a new string and assign it back to the key. You can do this with `list`s because the `list` is mutable, i.e. you can mutate the list in the dictionary.

For `str` just use `dict.get()`. This will append the value onto the existing value in the dictionary if it exists or to the empty string if it doesn't, e.g.:

```
d['Name'] = d.get('Name', '') + 'Name 1'
```

Alternatively, use a `collection.defaultdict`, e.g.:

```
d = defaultdict(str)
d['Name'] += 'Name 1'
```

Note: don't use `dict` as a variable name it hides pythons `dict` type.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to append 'Name' to the dictionary directly in a for loop and
>   if the name is not available, I want it to be an empty string

This can be done with just [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
dict.setdefault('Name', '')
```

Note: `dict` is a very bad name for a variable: it shadows the built-in type `dict`.

Comment: 'Name' is the key here. How can we assign a value to key?

Comment: @BharatBittu There is no direct assignment in my example. See the link to docs that i've posted: "If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default.". Here default is ```""``` (empty string)